# Unique elements

Tags: python, list

Given a list of numbers, find and print the elements that appear in it only once. Such elements should be printed in the order in which they occur in the original list.
So I use sort and use a list to keep track of it order but python say "list index out of range", how do I fix this?

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
a.sort()
mylist = []
myorder = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    if  a[i-1] != a[i] != a[i+1]:
        mylist.append(a[i])
        myorder.append(a.index(a[i]))
mylist = [mylist[k] for k in myorder]
print(mylist)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code should work:

```
a = [int(s) for s in input().split()]
sortedLst = sorted(a)
unique = []
uniqueOrd = []

for i in range(len(a) - 2):
  if sortedLst[i + 1] != sortedLst[i] and sortedLst[i + 1] != sortedLst[i + 2]:
    unique.append(sortedLst[i + 1])

for num in a:
  if num in unique:
    uniqueOrd.append(num)

print(uniqueOrd)
#1 5 3 4 2 6 1 3 4 6
```

Output with input (1 5 3 4 2 6 1 3 4 6):

```
[5, 2]
```

We make the range of our for loop `len(a) - 2` so that the max value of `i` is `len(a) - 3`, and the maximum element we access, `a[i + 2]`, is `a[len(a) - 1]`, or the last element of the list.

Starting from `i = 0`, we will check if the `i + 1`th element is equal to the `i`th or `i + 2`th element. If at least one of these equalities is true, the element is not unique. If the `i + 1`th element is not equal to either the `i`th or `i + 2`th element, we add it to our unique list.

To preserve the order from the original list, `a`, we iterate through `a`, and if the element in `a` is also found in `unique`, we add it to `uniqueOrd`, so the order is preserved.

I hope this helped! Please let me know if you have any further questions or clarifications :)

Comment: Given your input, the output should be [2, 5].

Comment: Didn’t they say to preserve order

Comment: Right, and it says "Output with input (1 2 3 4 5 6 1 3 4 6):" and then shows the 5 coming before the 2. Either the output shown is wrong, or the input is.

Comment: Yeah, I mistyped the input haha

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a for loop and accessing

```
a[i+1]
```

but by your definition in:

```
for i in range(len(a))
```

when `i` is its maximum value `i+1` is out of the index range of `a`.